# Construct linear homogeneus differential equation of 3rd order satisfied by functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do i find linear homogeneus differential equation of 3rd order satisfied by $e^t$, $t$,  $t^2$? First i tried looking for equation with constant coefficients, the characteristic polynomial would have to look like this: $(r-1)r^3$ so that solutions are  $e^t$,$1$ $t$, $t^2$ but that does not work since it is characteristic polynomial of 4th degree equation. I cannot figure out how to do this without just randomly guessing.

Comment: Maybe you should try a third order DE with non constant coefficients but linear and homogeneous....... Nowhere it's said that the DE must have constant coefficients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most general linear homogeneus 3rd order is

$$
y^{\prime\prime\prime}+Ay^{\prime\prime}+By^{\prime}+Cy=0
$$

For $y=e^{t}$ this gives

\begin{align}
e^{t}+Ae^{t}+Be^{t}+Ce^{t}  & =0\tag{1}\\
1+A+B+C  & =0\nonumber
\end{align}

For $y=t$ this gives

\begin{equation}
B+Ct=0\tag{2}%
\end{equation}

For $y=t^{2}$ this gives

\begin{equation}
2A+2Bt+Ct^{2}=0\tag{3}
\end{equation}

Three equations with 3 unknowns. Solving gives

\begin{align*}
A  & =-\frac{t^{2}}{\Delta}\\
B  & =\frac{2t}{\Delta}\\
C  & =\frac{-2}{\Delta}
\end{align*}

Where $\Delta=t^{2}-2t+2$. Hence the most general 3rd order ode is
$$
y^{\prime\prime\prime}-\frac{t^{2}}{t^{2}-2t+2}y^{\prime\prime}+\frac
{2t}{t^{2}-2t+2}y^{\prime}-\frac{2}{t^{2}-2t+2}y=0
$$